# Set bits before index without shift or LUT

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Let's say I need to set all bits before a specific bit index. Here are examples with 4 bits:

```
index(0) = (0x0, 0000)
index(1) = (0x1, 1000)
index(2) = (0x3, 1100)
index(3) = (0x7, 1110)
```

How can I do this without using shifts or a LUT, but instead using minimal bitwise operations or arithmetic or something similarly efficient?

Comment: bits counting starts from right to left usually

Comment: How does a shift not qualify as a minimal bitwise operation?

Comment: @JerryCoffin - it is implemented on some systems as multiple operations (GPUs for instance)

Comment: This is approximately a thousand times more difficult without a shift. You could implement a left-shift as adding a value to itself, but now you need an addition *per shift-count*, which transforms data-dependencies to control-flow dependencies, which is *even worse* on GPUs.

Comment: Multiplication is implemented as multiple operations on some systems as well. If I look hard, I can even find a few where subtraction is implemented as multiple operations. What of it?

Comment: @user1043761 can you give some links to this?

Comment: @Lashane That's what I commented. Unfortunately you need an addition per shift-count, which leads to control-flow dependency. You could avoid that with multiplication, but I doubt multiplication counts as a "minimal bitwise operation".

Comment: @EOF Multiplication throughput on GPUs is greater than shift throughput, and a different pipeline, maybe there is something there

Comment: @JerryCoffin GPUs aren't exactly obscure devices though...

Comment: @user1043761: Actually, come to think of it, multiplication doesn't really help much. You'd need a way to calculate `pow(2, shiftcount)`, for which the best you could do would probably exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to any language. It is a pure algorithm problem. Please state your actual problem. This looks more like some coding challenge.

Comment: @EOF - that is actually how early versions of CUDA emulated shifts :)

Comment: @Olaf The problem is very clearly stated, nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @user1043761: I'm asking for the **actual** problem you try to solve. Not just what you _think_ you have. This either is some challenge you should solve yourself, or a potential XY-problem. The operations supported by a CPU typically include bitshift, so they are very well "minimal". If your target does not support them (there is no CPU which does not), you need to state what you have in the armory.

Comment: @user1043761 where did you find information that cuda emulates shifts?

Comment: @Lashane - only link i could find: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/668623/integer-instructions-performance-on-kepler/

Comment: @user1043761 That thread discusses the emulation of rotates, which require emulation on many RISC architectures. Also, as 32-bit platforms (with 64-bit addressing capability) GPUs must emulate all 64-bit integer operations, including 64-bit shifts (using 32-bit shifts as building blocks). All GPUs that support CUDA have had 32-bit barrel shifters, newer ones even have 64:32-bit funnel shifters. So if you *need* a shift on a GPU, just use one.

Comment: @user1043761 I don't see any mention "shift emulation" in this thread, but for example [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_Further_CUDA_Optimization.pdf) I see that shifts have the same performance as add and multiplication is usually replaced with them

Comment: GPUs in general aren't obscure. GPUs that can't do bit shifting (if any exist at all) are pretty obscure.

Comment: I was given bad information and am wrong about the GPUs. Still leaving the question up fthough, I think it's a valid question, despite the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are very weird because you want efficient solution and cut of the only two means allowing to do it properly.

So you basically want to compute `x=(2^bit)-1` which is with bit-shift pretty easy:

```
x=(1<<bit)-1; // O(1)
```

With **LUT** also ... So how to attack this without the two:

```
x=pow(2,bit)-1; //O(?) can be O(1),O(log(n)),O(n)
```

Well this is far from efficient and `pow` also uses bit shift and some implementation also **LUT**. The only solutions left are:

1. **approximation**

   can use polynomial,PCA,or any other method ... but you need to consider the target range ... This is also not very optimal and robust. This can be `O(1),O(log(n)),O(n)` but usually with very slow constant time.
2. **emulate bit-shif left**

   you can do that with loop and addition:

   ```
   int x; for (x=1;bit;bit--) x+=x; x--;
   ```

   But this runs in `O(n)`. Anyway this is still faster then `pow` unless you got some `pow2` implemented on **HW**.

**[Notes]**

in the complexity formulas `n=bit` and all the code is in **C++** except the first formula where `^` means power.